# Angular Modal - Update the UI (object has moved to another date)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I'm using an Angular UI modal to update the calendar style grid UI. (on a drag and drop style app (using http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/types)), to e.g. change the date of an order planningslot.

The modal is to provide a manual way of updating and I can’t save until the user hits the Save button.

This is fine (though I suspect it could be better) in updating the data in my parent scope object (scope.WokCentres), i.e. the date changes, great). What I’m stuck on is ‘moving’ the object to it’s new date within the 'calendar style grid'
Below is my JS and view html

JS:

```
$scope.EditWorkOrder = function (slot, max) {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: '/app/WorkOrder/Views/EditWorkOrder.html',
            controller: 'EditWorkOrderCtrl as vm',
            size: 'lg',
            resolve: {
                data: function () {
                    return {
                        Slot: slot,
                        Max: max
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        //slotupdate is the returned object from the modal
        modalInstance.result.then(function (slotupdate) {
            for (var a = 0; a < scope.WorkCentres.length; a++) {
                var wcs = scope.WorkCentres[a]
                for (var b = 0; b < wcs.WorkOrderDates.length; b++) {
                    var wcd = wcs.WorkOrderDates[b]
                    for (var c = 0; c < wcd.PlanningSlots.length; c++) {
                        var slot = wcd.PlanningSlots[c]
                        if (slot.Id == slotupdate.Id) {
                            // This gets hit and updates the appropriate data object from the loop
                            scope.WorkCentres[a].WorkOrderDates[b].PlanningSlots[c] = slotupdate;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, function () {
            // do nothing
            // $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });            
    };//  END OF MODAL
```

VIEW:

```
<div ng-controller="workCentreCtrl as vm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="workcentre-left">
            <h3>Work Centre</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="workcentre-right">
            <ul>
                <li class="date-bar" ng-repeat="workdate in vm.WorkDates">{{workdate |date:'EEEE'}} {{workdate |date:'dd MMM'}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="wc in vm.WorkCentres" ng-model="vm.WorkCentres">
            <div class="workcentre-left">
                <h5>{{wc.WorkCentreName}}</h5>
                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open(wc.WorkCentreId)" type="button">edit</button>
                <p ng-if="wc.RouteTime != 0">{{wc.RouteTime}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="workcentre-right dndBoxes">
                <ul class="orderdate" ng-repeat="date in wc.WorkOrderDates" data-workdate="{{date.OrderDate}}">
                    <li id="parentorderdate" ng-class="{'four-slot': wc.max == 4, 'eight-slot': wc.max == 8, 'twelve-slot': wc.max == 12,'sixteen-slot': wc.max == 16}">
                        <ul dnd-list="date.PlanningSlots"
                            dnd-allowed-types="wc.allowedTypes"
                            dnd-disable-if="date.PlanningSlots.length >= wc.max"
                            dnd-dragover="dragoverCallback(event, index, external, type)"
                            dnd-drop="dropCallback(event, index, item, external, type, 'itemType')"
                            dnd-inserted="logEvent('Element was inserted at position ' + index, event)">
                            <li ng-repeat="slot in date.PlanningSlots" ng-model="date.PlanningSlots" ng-if="slot.WorkOrderNumber != '' "
                                dnd-draggable="slot"
                                dnd-type="wc.allowedTypes"
                                dnd-moved="date.PlanningSlots.splice($index, 1)"
                                dnd-effect-allowed="move" class="slot {{slot.css}}" title="{{slot.WOStatus}}">
                                <div>{{slot.SlotNumber}}</div>
                                <div>{{slot.WorkOrderNumber}} - {{slot.ProductDescription}}</div>
                                <div ng-if="slot.WOStatus != ''"><span class="float-right fa fa-edit fa-2x main-text edit-work-order" ng-click="EditWorkOrder(slot, wc.max)"></span></div>
                            </li>

                            <li ng-repeat="slot in date.PlanningSlots" ng-model="date.PlanningSlots" ng-if="slot.SlotBlocked == 'true'"
                                class="empty-slot">{{slot.SlotBlocked}}
                                <i class="fa fa-ban fa-2x main-text"></i>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dndPlaceholder">Drop work order here
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help many appreciated.
itsdanny

Answer (score 0):

The code in the OP, breaks the model (scope.WorkCentres). 
There is an angular.forEach function which doesn't

```
 modalInstance.result.then(function (slotupdate) {
                // Remove it
                angular.forEach(scope.WorkCentres, function (wc) {
                    angular.forEach(wc.WorkOrderDates, function (WorkOrderDate) {
                        angular.forEach(WorkOrderDate.PlanningSlots, function (slot) {
                            if (slot.Id == slotupdate.Id) {
                                WorkOrderDate.PlanningSlots.splice(index, 1);

                            }
                        })
                    })
                })
                // Add it back
                angular.forEach(scope.WorkCentres, function (wc) {
                    if (wc.WorkCentreId == slotupdate.WorkCentreId) {
                        angular.forEach(wc.WorkOrderDates, function (WorkOrderDate) {
                            if (WorkOrderDate.OrderDate == slotupdate.OrderDate.getTime()) {
                                WorkOrderDate.PlanningSlots.push(slotupdate)
                                return;
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })                
            }
```

I might actually cry out of joy!